# magento 2 can't use same url key for different store view pages

Tags: magento2, multistore, language

I have 2 store views on my website, one in English and one in Italian, I'm trying to set different privacy and cookie page for each view, but I need to use the same URL key, to auto-redirect to the right page.

But when I try to set the URL on the different page view I get this error:

> URL key for specified store already exists.

I read [here](http://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/create-store-views-in-multi-languages-and-translated-products-content-in-magento-2/) how to do, but It doesn't work